# shell-command で独自補完を定義するには？

Tags: emacs, elisp

<kbd>M-!</kbd> でシェルコマンドが実行できますが、この際のミニバッファでの入力の <kbd>TAB</kbd> 補完を独自定義できますか？

具体的には、 rake コマンドの補完が zsh ではできているが、emacs のコマンド実行の際にはできていないのを不便に感じたので、どうにかしたいと思い質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pcmpl-args.el: Enhanced shell completion in Emacs](https://github.com/JonWaltman/pcmpl-args.el) というパッケージがあります。ELPA repository に登録されていますので package-install や el-get でインストールできます。

具体的なコードは以下になります。

```
(require 'pcmpl-args)

(defun pcomplete/rake ()
  (require 'cl-extra)
  (pcmpl-args-pcomplete
   (pcmpl-args-cached 'rake t
     (pcmpl-args-make-argspecs
      (append
       (pcmpl-args-extract-argspecs-from-manpage "rake")
       `((argument * (("RAKE-TARGET"
          (:eval
           (let ((rakefile
                  (cl-some 'file-exists-p '("rakefile" "Rakefile" "rakefile.rb" "Rakefile.rb"))))
             (when rakefile
               (let* ((cache (pcmpl-args-cache-get 'rake-targets))
                      (ac (assoc (expand-file-name default-directory) cache))
                      (comp (if ac (cdr ac)
                              (cl-remove-if '(lambda (tg) (string= tg ""))
                                            (split-string
                                             (shell-command-to-string "rake -sT 2>/dev/null | cut -d' ' -f2") "\n")))))
                 (unless ac
                   (pcmpl-args-cache-put 'rake-targets
                                         (append cache
                                                 (list (append
                                                        (list (expand-file-name default-directory))
                                                        comp))) t))
                 (completion-table-in-turn comp))))))))))))))
```

`default-directory` に `Rakefile` などがあるかどうかを確認して、あれば `rake -sT ...` を実行して rule target を抽出します。抽出結果(補完候補)は `default-directory` とペアにして cache に登録しておきます。

これで zsh の様な補完が可能になるのですが、いくつか問題があります。まず、Rakefile の変更に対応していません。現状では cache の寿命がデフォルトで 10 秒ですので、その間隔内では齟齬が生じる事になります。Rakefile の timestamp や message digest を記録しておくなどして cache を適宜更新する様に変更すると良いかもしれません。次に、default-directory 内にある Rakefile のみを対象にしている点です。つまり、rake の `-f` option で別のディレクトリにある Rakefile を指定した場合、期待する動作になりません。